# Find surrounding characters of an element inside a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have this little problem. I need to find the first 3 characters before and after an anchor tag that is inside a paragraph.

Example:

```
<p>This is <a href='#' id='lock'>a</a> test for an anchor</p>
```

What I need to have as a result is:

```
is  te
```

Where `is` (includes space at the end) is the first 3 characters left from the anchor tag and `te` (again including space at start) are the 3 first characters right from the anchor tag.

JQuery can help and so far I tried with regex and Jquery but no luck.

What else should I try? Is there something I might be missing?
It had been a while since I worked with frontend problems.

Comment: Simple string functions should do the trick. I'm thinking `indexOf()` and `substring()` or `substr()` . But I may miss something in your question cause that's quite a simple answer...

Comment: @Bartdude this is what i was thinking but it was a bit more tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
var lock = document.getElementById('lock');
var prev = lock.previousSibling;
var next = lock.nextSibling;

var text = prev.textContent.slice(-3) + next.textContent.slice(0, 3);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MZ4L5/)

Comment: Your answer was also correct and I liked it the most but I marked @VisionN 's answer as correct because he answered first. Thanks very much!

Comment: @JimmyKane - What, Vision answered last !

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I made a mistake.

Comment: @JimmyKane - I answered second last, but you should really accept the answer you decided to use, or that helped you the most, if it was several answers, accept the one that was posted first among those answers etc. At the end of the day it's all up to you, you can accept whatever you want.

Comment: Did as you said. Your answer was direct for me and with no edits. All the people answered in a nice way.

Comment: *VisioN* doesn't really care which answer was accepted. The main goal of our community is to help people to find solutions. If the answer is valid it may deserve upvotes showing to others that it is useful and is worth to be read and re-used. If two or many answers are *equally* valid usually the first answer is accepted, however the decision is always made individually.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex to capture the there characters before and after anchor a tag,

```
(.{3})<a href.*?<\/a>(.{3})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oX4qT1/8)

If you want to replace the whole with only the captured groups then your regex would be,

```
.*(.{3})<a href.*?<\/a>(.{3}).*
```

And the substitution would be,

```
$1$2
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oX4qT1/7)

And your code would be,

```
> var str = "<p>This is <a href='#' id='lock'>a</a> test for an anchor</p>";
undefined
> var r = str.replace(/.*(.{3})<a href.*?<\/a>(.{3}).*/g, "$1$2");
undefined
> console.log(r);
is  te
undefined
```

Comment: What about in this string "<p>This is not <a test <a href='#' id='lock'>a</a> test for an anchor</p>"?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I prefered not to go with a regex for several reasons but it explained a lot. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.contents()` to grab the text nodes,

```
var pTag = $('p').contents();
console.log(pTag[0].nodeValue.slice(-3) +
                  pTag[2].nodeValue.substring(0,3)); // "is  te"
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H2ScF/2/;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though it was the first one, I focused on another one. I should say that your answer was complete now that I took the time

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with jQuery and DOM traversing:

```
var a = $("a", "<p>This is <a href='#'>a</a> test for an anchor</p>")[0],
    left = a.previousSibling.nodeValue.slice(-3),
    right = a.nextSibling.nodeValue.slice(0, 3);

console.log(left, right);  // "is " " te"
```

Comment: Thank you and the rest for showing me `previousSibling` and `nextSibling`. Btw you don't need contents eh...

Comment: @JimmyKane Yes, indeed. I forgot to remove the note about `contents` after updating the solution with more straightforward approach.